# Windows command to print only common lines in two or more files

Tags: windows, shell, diff, compare, comm

Something like `comm` but for Windows (No, installing Cygwin just for this is not a good idea.) It will be great if it will allow compare more than 2 files at once. Example for 2 files:

File1:

```
foo1
foo2
foo3
bar
```

File2:

```
bar
foo2
```

Output:

```
foo2
bar
```

(or in reverse order). Whitespace not have to be ignored (but it can), it's already normalized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CoreUtils for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm)

Comment: try this: `comm -12 file1 file2`

Comment: Since the `comm` command is a part of the CoreUtils, then assuming you install CoreUtils correctly, it should work just as well on windows as any other system.

Comment: [CoreUtils for Windows via Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/packages/gnuwin32-coreutils.install), but note that PATH is not setup automatically.